# Parent's controller method called in child

Tags: angularjs

I want to get $scope variable value from "inherited" controller. It works for non-scope var but for scope var prints undefined.

```
appControllers.controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', '$log',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, $log) {

        $scope.someVariable = "Scope hello world.";

        $scope.getLocalVariable = function (){
            return "hello world";
        }

        $scope.getScopeVariable = function (){
            return $scope.someVariable;
        }

    }]);


appControllers.controller('childCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', '$log',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, $log) {

        $log.debug($scope.getLocalVariable());  // this WORKS

        $log.debug($scope.getScopeVariable());  // this DOES NOT WORKS - prints undefined

    }]);
```

part of .html file

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
<div ng-controller="childCtrl">
</div>
</div>
```

Do you have any idea? I also tried

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('ParentCtrl ', function($scope) {
  // I'm the sibling, but want to act as parent
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
  var ctrl = $controller('ParentCtrl', {$scope: $scope}); 
  ctrl.methodCall() // DOES NOT WORK

});
```

But it did not helped. Thanks

Comment: You should define all functions in parent controller in $scope. Then u will have no problems.   $scope.getScopeVariable  = function () ...

Comment: Sorry, I copied it incorectly from my code. Of course I use $scope.getScopeVariable = function ().  I have already edited the question code. So, your advice does not work.

Comment: I am using  Angular 1.2.28

Comment: @jiri463 try the latest stable version of angular (1.3). Your code is working for me

Comment: Seems to work fine in 1.2.28 as well - can you create a plunker and reproduce? Here's one with your code working: http://plnkr.co/edit/2EDcIb4ll7GMJtlKHGvm?p=preview